I have a proof that the axiom of infinity leads to contradiction, I must be wrong but cannot see why
So I have convinced myself that the axiom of infinity is false and I have a proof. However, I have no delusions of grandeur about my intellect so it seems far more likely that I'm wrong than that no mathematician before me came up with this. I would like to know why I'm wrong.
The proof:
Definition 1 (von Neumann ordinal): Let $S^n(\emptyset)$ be defined by:
$S(x)=x \cup \{x\} \textrm{ and } S^{n+1}(x)=S(S^n(x))$
Such that $S^n(\emptyset)=n$.
Definition 2 (identifier sequence): Let $I_n$ be a sum that adds $1$ for every element of $S^n(\emptyset)$, modulo 1:
$I_n = \sum_{i \in S^n(\emptyset)} 1 \pmod{1}= \sum_{i=0}^n 1 \pmod{1} = n+1 \pmod{1} = n \pmod{1}$
Lemma 1: $\lim_{n\to\infty}S^n(\emptyset)=\mathbb{N}$.
Proof: If $x$ is an element of $S^k(\emptyset)$ then $x$ will also be an element of $S^l(\emptyset)$ for all $l>k$. So that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we know that $n\in n+1$ and therefore $n\in S^\infty(\emptyset)$. Moreover, for any $n\in S^\infty(\emptyset)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by definition. $\Box$
Lemma 2: if $x \equiv 0 \pmod 1 $ and $x \geq 0$ then $x \in \mathbb{N}$.
Proof: $0 \equiv 0 \pmod 1 $, $0=0$ and $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Assume $n \equiv 0 \pmod 1$ and $n\geq 0$ implies $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $n \geq 0$. Now assume that $n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 1$. Clearly $1 \equiv 0\pmod 1$, therefore:
$n = n+1-1 \equiv 0+0\pmod 1 = 0\pmod 1 $
Therefore if $n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 1$, then $n \equiv 0 \pmod 1$. Because of the induction hypothesis we can now claim $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now by the axiom of infinity, $n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$. $\Box$
Lemma 3: $I_\infty=0$.
Proof: No $\epsilon >0$ is required. $I_n=0$ for all $n$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=0$. $\Box$
Theorem: The axiom of infinity is false.
Proof: The axiom of infinity posits that $\mathbb{N}$ exists. By Lemma 1, $S^\infty(\emptyset)=\mathbb{N}$. By Lemma 2 and 3, $S^\infty(\emptyset)\in\mathbb{N}$. But now $\mathbb{N}\in\mathbb{N}$, which is a contradiction to the axiom of foundation. $\Box$

How does $I_n=0$ for all n including the limit show that $S^\infty (\emptyset) \in \mathbb{N}$?

Because $I_x=0$ implies $x \equiv 0 \pmod{1}$ by definition, which implies $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by lemma 2.

It is a bit unclear what your actual reasoning is, due to the abuse of notation. First of all, $S^{\infty}$ is not defined by your recursive formula, neither have you defined what you mean by $\mathbb{N}$ (It seems you want to define it as the union of $S^n$ but then the lemma makes no sense, at it is just an introduction of the notation $S^{\infty}$.) Secondly, lemma 2 does not make sense, your assumptions on $x$ are already only applicable to natural numbers, (What does $x\geq 0$ mean for an arbitrary set $x$?) hence your lemma amounts to "Natural numbers are natural numbers"

I have edited lemma 1. You are right, I was unclear about the meaning of $S^\infty(\emptyset)$. I meant the limit of $S^n(\emptyset)$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

unfortunately this doesn't rectify it, you are still making a statement about an object which you call $\mathbb{N}$. What needs to be clear before you can evaluate such a statement is what exactly the object $\mathbb{N}$ is (I'm pointing this out because it is usually defined to be exactly the thing you claim it equals) And once that is sorted out, you need to also say what you mean by the limit of the sequence $S^n$ since this certainly is not a limit in the sense of analysis.

"Lemma 1: $\lim_{n\to\infty}S^n(\emptyset)=\mathbb{N}$." This is not a meaningful statement, because a limit is usually only defined for real numbers (or more generally for elements of a topological space). It is not defined for sets. Are you trying to say that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}S^n(\emptyset)=\mathbb{N}$?

I meant to say "The set we obtain when we apply $S$ to $\emptyset$ an infinite number of times"

Also, what do you mean by $a \equiv b \text{ (mod } 1 \text{)}$? Do you mean $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} : a + n = b$?

Yes that is what I meant.

And what type of object is $I_n$? A real number? If so, I don't understand which real number $I_n$ is supposed to be.

The real number 0. My idea for the proof was to show that the sequence of sets $S^n(\emptyset)$ never stops being a natural number, while the limit is the set of all natural numbers.

"By Lemma 2 and 3, $S^\infty(\emptyset)\in\mathbb{N}$" How so? Lemma 2 is a statement about real numbers, but $S^\infty(\emptyset)$ is not a real number.

You apply continuity, but what's the justification for that? There are discontinuous things too.

@ OP, “ "The set we obtain when we apply S to ∅ an infinite number of times" — this is loose talk. You haven’t defined infinite application. There’s no topology involved so “limit” is the wrong term; you probably mean union, or a comprehension.

As it doesn't seem like you intend to fix the errors pointed out, I will rewrite your argument, attempting to fix each step in isolation, so that it becomes clear which steps do and do not follow from the previous steps. Since your proof uses the natural numbers throughout, I will assume that you are working in a context where these are already defined.
Definition 1:
Define $S^n(\emptyset) := n$, further, from my definition of $\mathbb{N}$, $n+1 = n\cup \{n\}$.

Under the assumption that your definition makes sense (which requires $\mathbb{N}$ to be defined) This definition is clearly equivalent to yours.

Definition 2:
Define $I_n := [0]_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}}$

You only define $I_n$ for natural numbers, and it so happens that $I_n$ is always $0$, so this is equivalent to your definiton

Definition/proposition 3:
Define:
$$S^{\infty} := \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}n$$ then
$$S^{\infty} = \mathbb{N}$$
proof: Suppose $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $n+1 = n\cup\{n\}$ so $n \in n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, hence $n\in S^{\infty}.$ For the other direction, suppose $n\in S^{\infty}$. Then define $$K := \{m\in \mathbb{N}|n\in m\}$$By our assumption, $K$ is non-empty. Thus let $m_0$ be its minimum, then $n\in m_0 = m_0 -1\cup \{m_0-1\}$. Since $m_0$ was miminal, $n\notin m_0-1$ thus $n = m_0-1 \in \mathbb{N}$.
Lemma: If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \geq 0$ then $x\in \mathbb{N}$. This follows from whatever definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ you use.
Lemma: Define $$I_{\infty} := \lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = [0]_{\mathbb{Z}}$$

This is a particularly strange step, to interpret this limit, we need to give $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ a metric structure, since it has only one point namely $0$, it can have only one metric, and then this limit is indeed trivial.

Theorem:
(Not sure what this theorem should be changed to, I can't really tell what its trying to prove)
$$S^{\infty} = \mathbb{N}$$
$$I_{\infty} = [0]_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}} \neq 0$$
Note that since $I_{\infty}$ is not an integer, we cannot apply the first lemma to it.
The purpose of this rewrite is not to produce a valid proof, but to show you that if you're careful and precise about what you mean, then what remains is just a collection of mostly unrelated definitions and trivial propositions that follow from these definitions.

Thanks, I understand my foolish ways now. Sorry to have wasted everybody's time.
